# google analytics does not work in my app?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-play-services

i use these codes for google analytics:
build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

build.gradle app :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

class AnalyticsApplication :

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics;
private static Tracker sTracker;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
}
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (sTracker == null) {
        sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }

    return sTracker;
}}
```

xml global_tracker :

```
   <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-******-*</string>
```

MainActivity :

```
        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.setScreenName("MainActivity");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

and the manifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
```

but after the 3 days GA not received any data or event. i check realtime and other options too,but there is nothing!
what is the problem?